# iPhone Cocos2D - list of blending modes available for a sprite and how to set them

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am googling around to find a list of all blending modes allowed by sprites on Cocos2D, but could not find one. Quartz can do these blending modes, and I am sure Cocos2D can do it too.

- ModeNormal
- ModeMultiply
- ModeScreen
- ModeOverlay
- ModeDarken
- ModeLighten
- ModeColorDodge
- ModeColorBurn
- ModeSoftLight
- ModeHardLight
- ModeDifference
- ModeExclusion
- ModeHue
- ModeSaturation
- ModeColor
- ModeLuminosity

The only one I could find on google was "additive", that I think is screen. That is set like this:

```
[proxy setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE }];  // example of additive blending
```

I am not even sure if this is screen.

So, where do I find such a list and instructions on how to set each one?

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will find a [detailed description of OpenGL blend modes here](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter06.html). And if you want to try things out, there's a wonderful [visual glBlendFunc online tool](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php).